# Android : error when using a runnable in an async task

Tags: android

I want to update a variable in my activity once every one second and for that i am using an Async task and a runnable inside it. I keep getting this error saying "Cannot refer to a non-final variable myRunnable inside an inner class defined in a different method" . When i change the declaration to final , it shows "The local variable myRunnable may not have been initialized" . How do i rectify the error? Is there a better way of doing what i want to do?

```
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Handler;

    public class Timer extends AsyncTask<String, Process, Void>{
static int seconds=0;
TimerTask timer;
static int minutes=0;
static int hours=0;
private String timeTaken;
public Handler myhandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

   final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    ......
......
    ...... 
myhandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
}
};

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this instead of using an AsyncTask (although something similar can be done within an AsyncTask, and because it runs in another thread I could simply block this worker thread using Thread.sleep(...) instead of doing the whole Runnable thing...

```
private myhandler = new Handler();
private boolean periodicCallsEnabled=false;

public boolean isPeriodicUpdatingEnabled(){
    return periodicCallsEnabled;
}

public void startPeriodicUpdates(){ //CALL THIS IN ORDER TO START THE PERIODIC UPDATES
    periodicCallsEnabled=true;
    periodicCall();
}

public void stopPeriodicUpdates(){ //CALL THIS TO STOP THEM
    periodicCallsEnabled=false;
    myhandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}


void periodicCall(){
    if(periodicCallsEnabled){

        //INSERT CUSTOM CODE HERE TO BE EXECUTED EVERY SECOND
        // ......

        myhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                periodicCall();
            }
        },1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using invoking the startPeriodicUpdates in my onCreate method. however when i press the back button and open the app in the emulator again, the onCreate gets called again. How do i fix this?

Comment: When you press the back button, it surely calls onDestroy (see the Android Activity Lifecycle graph in Google's documentation). I presume that you call stopPeriodicUpdates() in your onDestroy method? Else, if what you want is for the startPeriodicUpdates() method to only be called the first time someone loads up your app, not afterwards (i.e. not when someone closes your app down and opens it again), then you might want to store the state of your app in something more permanent, such as a SharedPreferences object...